# How to match variables against parameters in mysqli_stmt_bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, full-text-search, relevance

Slightly odd one this and any help would be appreciated.

```
$rs_contact = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
SELECT CONTACTID, COMPANY, FORENAME, SURNAME, MATCH (FORENAME, SURNAME) AGAINST ('?') AS relevance 
FROM CONTACTS
WHERE MATCH (FORENAME, SURNAME) AGAINST ('?')
ORDER BY relevance DESC
");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rs_contact, "ss", $q_string, $q_string);// bind parameters
mysqli_stmt_execute($rs_contact);// execute query
mysqli_stmt_store_result($rs_contact);// store result - needed for longtext fields
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($rs_contact, $CONTACTID, $COMPANY, $FORENAME, $SURNAME, $relevance);// bind result variables
$rowcount_contact = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($rs_contact);
```

This returns an error

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /search.php on line XX
```

It's not the first time I've used multiple parameters but is the first time I've had to use the same variable against both parameter slots.

It's probably a simple schoolboy error but I can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: `?` is a placeholder, `'?'` is a string with a question mark.

Comment: Sorry - thank you  - good call and it works.